# Unhandled Promise rejection: No provider for [object Object]! ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: No provider for [object Object]!

Tags: angular, ngrx

I'm trying to add ngrx effect to my angular app.

I made an effect like this ->

```
import { HttpService } from './../../../shared/services/common/http.service';
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import * as ItemsListActions from './itemsList.actions';

@Injectable()
export class ItemsListEffects {
  // Listen for the 'LOGIN' action
  constructor(@Inject(HttpService) private _http: HttpService, @Inject(ItemsListActions) private _actions$: ItemsListActions) {}
}
```

I removed the content cause the error appear all the time anyway

In appModule I have

```
    @NgModule({
        imports: [
            EffectsModule.forRoot([ItemsListEffects]),
        ]
    })
```

but when I compile I have

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: No provider for [object Object]! ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: No provider for [object Object]!
```

If I comment the import, no error.

But I don't understand my mistake

Comment: _Why_ did you write the effect like that? It's not how it should be done. Any specific reason? You should use the `@Effect()` decorator.

Comment: actually I am copying from here https://ngrx.io/guide/effects

I just removed the @Effect() for testing, cause I believe the problem is somewhere else

Comment: @DanielB if is for the inject inside the constructor, they are required in the app I work for else the app doesn't work.

Comment: And you're registering the `StoreModule.forRoot()` before you register your `EffectsModule`?

Comment: both way do the same error

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the `@Inject`'ed properties in the constructor aren't provided by the module.